# Why does pgfplots's "current plot style" throw an error even when it works?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors

I managed to produce the following diagram with pgfplots and Ti*k*Z:

[image: LaTeX output: a pV diagram for three thermodynamic processes]

This is exactly how I want it to look.
The following M(-ish)WE reproduces the diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0, xmax=1,
      ymin=0, ymax=1,
      enlargelimits=true,
      xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
      xlabel={$V$},
      ylabel={$p$},
      axis lines=middle,
      domain=0:1,
      variable=\t,
      no marks,
      samples=24,
      smooth,
    ]
    %
    % Isochoric process, halving temperature
    \addplot (0.25, 0.75-0.5*t);
    \begin{scope}[current plot style]
      \fill (axis cs:0.25, 0.25) circle (2pt) node[below] {isochoric};
    \end{scope}
    %
    % Isothermal process, halving pressure
    \addplot (0.1875/(0.75-0.5*t), 0.75-0.5*t);
    \begin{scope}[current plot style]
      \fill (axis cs:0.75, 0.25) circle (2pt) node[below] {isothermal};
    \end{scope}
    %
    % Isobaric process, doubling volume
    \addplot (0.25+0.25*t, 0.75);
    \begin{scope}[current plot style]
      \fill (axis cs:0.5, 0.75) circle (2pt) node[below] {isobaric};
    \end{scope}
    %
    \fill[black] (axis cs:0.25, 0.75) circle (2pt) node[above] {initial state};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I'm using the `scope`s to make the points and labels (isochoric, isobaric, isothermal) have the same color as the most recent plots.
I like this approach because it's mathematically elegant (parametric in time instead of just `\draw`ing) and because I can use pgfplots's cycle list instead of explicitly specifying any colors.

However, despite the correct output, I get the following error message three times:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/current plot style' and I
 am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.28     \begin{scope}[current plot style]
```

If I remove the `scope`s or their arguments, the error goes away, but then the labels are black.

Is this related to the statement in the pgfplots manual (section 4.3, "The `\addplot` Command: Coordinate Input"; p. 42) that legend options "are available as ‘`current plot style`’ as long as the path is not yet finished or in associated error bars"?
I'm not sure whether that means that the whole `current plot style` style is only available in that case, or if it's just the legend entries that are scoped as such.

In any case, what should I do to correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why the key `current plot style` produces errors when given as a `scope` option. As far as I can tell, it should work fine, especially considering the rest of my answer.

But (and in my opinion this is more elegant) it *does* work if just added as an option to each `\fill`, like this:

```
\fill[current plot style] (axis cs:0.25, 0.25) circle (2pt) node[below] {isochoric};
```

Here's the complete code, which compiles without errors:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0, xmax=1,
      ymin=0, ymax=1,
      enlargelimits=true,
      xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
      xlabel={$V$},
      ylabel={$p$},
      axis lines=middle,
      domain=0:1,
      variable=\t,
      no marks,
      samples=24,
      smooth,
    ]
    %
    % Isochoric process, halving temperature
    \addplot (0.25, 0.75-0.5*t);
    \fill[current plot style] (axis cs:0.25, 0.25) circle (2pt) node[below] {isochoric};
    %
    % Isothermal process, halving pressure
    \addplot (0.1875/(0.75-0.5*t), 0.75-0.5*t);
    \fill[current plot style] (axis cs:0.75, 0.25) circle (2pt) node[below] {isothermal};
    %
    % Isobaric process, doubling volume
    \addplot (0.25+0.25*t, 0.75);
    \fill[current plot style] (axis cs:0.5, 0.75) circle (2pt) node[below] {isobaric};
    %
    \fill[black] (axis cs:0.25, 0.75) circle (2pt) node[above] {initial state};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]